# The integer values of $c$ for which a quotient is an integer

Tags: divisibility

I want to find all the integer values of $c$ for which $\frac{c^6-3}{c^2+2}$ is an integer.

By inspection $\pm 3$ is a solution. However, is there any systematic way to find all the solutions?

Comment: Hint : $c^2+2\mid c^6+8$ implies $c^2+2\mid 11$

Comment: @Peter thanks it solved the problem